# What is the right way to pass value from php to r

Tags: php, r, rapache

I'm trying to pass a variable value from my php code to the r processing environment.

for example:

```
<?php

$val=5;

?>

<%

print (val)

%>
```

Obviously this doesn't work.

What is the right way to do it?

Thaks,

Yoni.

**Update**

I'm using rapache.

It works, but I would like to use php the react with the client.

Comment: IMHO, the right way to do it is to leave PHP. Forget about it. Use `brew`! =)

Comment: I've merged your two unregistered accounts, you should be able to edit your question and comment under answers now.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your options are

- Pass your arguments from PHP to some pre-written R script using a combination of the PHP exec() command and Rscript
- look into [rapache](http://rapache.net/)
- or see if you can find anything in the [R FAQ on Web interfaces](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#R-Web-Interfaces)

At least that's what I've been able to come up with.

Comment: Hi,

Maybe i should have write it in my last msg, But I'm using rapache.

It works, but I would like to use php the react with the client.

Does anyone know how to it's done?

Comment: There's a sample in the [cook book](http://rapache.net/manual.html#rapache_Cookbook) section of the rapache manual.  Basically it looks like you call your rApache app and pass in your parameters in either a get, post, cookie, or a file on your OS.  But definitely check out the [manual](http://rapache.net/manual.html) it goes into way more detail than I can here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm new to this, so the cook book is hard for me to understand.
Maybe if you can help me with the next question I will be able to fix something.
Is there a way to use GET/POST without the "input" argument. I mean can I give the variable a value and not to wait for the client to press for example the submit buttem?
If so, than I understend how to pass the varibels to r.